# How can i start android.wallpaper.livepicker system process on button press?

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

A very simple question that is actually stated in the title.
Let's say i got this:

```
button button_one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button_one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          **Wanna open android.wallpaper.livepicker system process here**
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
button button_one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button_one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      Intent i = new Intent(WallpaperManager.ACTION_LIVE_WALLPAPER_CHOOSER);
startActivity(i);
```

Try it..

Comment: Just perfect :)
I was wondering if it is possible to start 2 activities as well. (the other just showing a little dialog message on top of the livepicker process)